# Consider Vector of Child Pointers as Vector of Base Pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose there are the following classes:

```
class A {

};

class B: public A {

};
```

and the vector of unique_ptr to B:
`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>> bElements`
Is there a possibility to pass the vector to a function that accepts
`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>&` as a parameter

Comment: no. not without copying to the new vector

Comment: if the function would take iterators and would be templated on the exact type of the iterator, you could pass iterators to either of the two vectors

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem? Why do you have a vector of pointer to `B`? Why not a vector of pointers to `A` (which, assuming polymorphic classes, should work)? Why does the function take a (reference to) a vector of pointer to `A` and not `B`? Can you use overloading? Or iterators (as mentioned by @463035818_is_not_a_number), which is really the "standard" way to handle containers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the vector of B (let's call it `b`) is stored as member of one class and I would like to pass the reference to the vector to other class (it is also saved as a reference class member, let's call it 'a') - the second class knows nothing of class B and at the same time if something is removed or added to the vector `b` I would like it to automatically reflect the contents  of `a`

Comment: It's not possible even with "raw" pointers, since it's not safe. Consider what would happen if the function replaced an element with a `std::unique_ptr<C>`, where `C` also inherits from `A`. You need to rethink your structure.

Comment: @molbdnilo the argumentation makes sense. But if the reference was const - such a problem would not be a problem

Comment: @molbdnilo of course, I understand, that it is not simply allowed in C++

Comment: Consider the `const_cast`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A `std::vector<Foo>` has no special relation to a `std::vector<Bar>` no matter what is the relation between `Foo` and `Bar`. They are two distinct completely different types. The fact that they are instantiations of the same class template is not relevant when you are asking for an exact type of argument of the function.

Thouh, the fact that they are instantiations of the same template enables you to employ duck typing. Make the function a function template. It can take either a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` or simply a container of type `C`, or iterators of type `Iter`. As you know the base class `B` you know how the ducks walk and how the ducks quack and can implement the function template so it will work with either `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>`.

("the ducks" is the classes inheriting from `A` and "how they walk and how they quack" is the interface of `A`)